# How to create a select join between 2 tables with limitations

Tags: mysql, sql

English is not my native language, so I apologize in advance for the mistakes...

Well, I have 3 MySQL tables:

```
users:
- Id    INT 11
- Name  VARCHAR 30

calls:
- Id         INT 11
- UserId     INT 11
- DateBegin  DATETIME
- DateEnd    DATETIME
- Phone      VARCHAR 30

contacts:
- Id      INT 11
- UserId  INT 11
- Name    VARCHAR 40
- Phone1  VARCHAR 30
- Phone2  VARCHAR 30

Relationship:
1 user -> many calls (users.Id - calls.UserId)
1 user -> many contacts (users.Id - contacts.UserId)
```

I need to list all the calls from an specific user, and join it with their contacts, by phone numbers. Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT
    calls.Id,
    calls.DateBegin,
    calls.DateEnd,
    calls.Phone,
    contacts.Name
FROM
    calls LEFT JOIN contacts ON
        RIGHT(calls.Number, 8) = RIGHT(contacts.Phone1, 8) OR
        RIGHT(calls.Number, 8) = RIGHT(contacts.Phone2, 8)
WHERE
    calls.UserId = 1 AND contacts.UserId = 1 
GROUP BY
    calls.Id
ORDER BY
    calls.DateBegin DESC;
```

There are 2 problems with this code I can't solve:

1. It lists only the calls that have a contact related. If I remove the "AND contacts.UserId = 1" in the WHERE clause it works, but contacts from another users is related in the join;
2. Sometimes the phone number is an empty string, so it gets first contact with empty number and create the join. I need it to ignore the contact when calls.phone is empty.

Please, can some SQL expert help me? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you are joining on right (x,8) of the numbers.  is there something wrong with with the first 22 characters?

Comment: two inner joins that with the ON condition `users.Id = calls.UserId = contacts.UserId`. And for the empty contact number WHERE `contact.Phone <> ""`

Comment: @Hogan, must of time the phone numbers are recorded in database in different format (mask). Some start with country code, other start with area code, etc. Comparing last 8 numbers will assure the real phone number (I think)...

Comment: @RyanVincent, I need to list all calls from the specify user, even if there are no contacts linked.

Comment: @Guybrush - so the numbers `555-5555` and `(212)5555555` are not the same?

Comment: @Hogan, I'm from Brazil, and here all phone numbers are at least 8 numbers long (without area code and country code). That's why I am doing like this...

Comment: @Guybrush -- ok but you are ignoring my point.  I did a search on your numbers and I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia -- so I will re-phrase my question: so the number `5555 5555` and `55 555 555` are not the same?  (I believe you could have figured out my point without this example)

Comment: @Hogan, now I understood your point, thank you! When making or receiving a call where the number is without country code or area code, I will automatically add this information, so I can compare the full number...

Comment: @Guybrush -- I think my point was about normalization in general.  You need some sort of formatting normalization with phone numbers or you can't compare them.  You could also do a formatting agnostic hash.

Comment: @Hogan, sorry, english is not my native language, but I understood your point! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition on the *second* table should be in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.DateBegin, c.DateEnd, c.Phone, MAX(co.Name) as Name
FROM calls c LEFT JOIN
     contacts co
     ON (RIGHT(c.Number, 8) = RIGHT(co.Phone1, 8) OR
         RIGHT(c.Number, 8) = RIGHT(co.Phone2, 8)
        ) AND co.UserId = 1 
WHERE c.UserId = 1
GROUP BY c.Id
ORDER BY c.DateBegin DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I also added " AND (c.Number IS NOT NULL AND c.Number != "")" in the ON clause for solving the 2nd. question. Please, can you explain why did you use MAX in the contact name?

Comment: @Guybrush . . . Because the aggregation needs to choose one value for `co.Name`.  The `MAX()` is deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

try the equal join by grouping conditions and matching on ID and then providing the specific id:

```
SELECT
    ca.ID
    ca.DateBegin,
    ca.DateEnd,
    ca.Phone,
    contacts.Name
FROM
    calls ca , contacts co 
Where
    calls.Id = contacts.UserId
    AND(
        RIGHT(ca.Number, 8) = RIGHT(co.Phone1, 8) OR
        RIGHT(ca.Number, 8) = RIGHT(co.Phone2, 8) )
AND
    ca.UserId = 1
AND 
   (ca.Phone is not null OR ca.Phone != " ")
GROUP BY
    ca.Id
ORDER BY
    ca.DateBegin DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to understand and use your code. What I don't understand is why you used WHERE "calls.Id = contacts.UserId", but I make tests and let you know...

Comment: Sorry! it should be ca.ID as per your table schema. let me know if u get any particular syntax error.